# How do I change the colour of the NSBox Title in swift for macOS OS X?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsbox

I am trying to get the window to appear with a black transparent feeling, by setting the window to alpha 0.9, and black. That is not the issue though. My issue is that I have NSBoxes in this window, and by changing the background to black, I cannot see the title of the NSBox properly. Is there a way to programatically change this? I prefer it be programatically compared to within the storyboard because I am also giving the user an option for "Light Mode" or "Dark Mode".

I am working on this project in Swift 3, for macOS.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can use below code to change box title color

```
let boxcell = boxContent.titleCell as! NSTextFieldCell
boxcell.textColor = .white
```

Thanks